# IN operator + SWITCH

Tags: powerbi, dax

There must be something very obvious that I'm missing here. I am using `SWITCH` function to create circa 20 bars on a bar chart that cumulate values from a different table.

```
SWITCH(
    VALUE(SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[RowNo])),
    1, CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] IN {"0-5", "05-10"}),
    2, CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] IN {"10-15", "15-20"}),
    3, CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] IN {"20-25", "25-30"}),
    ...
)
```

I thought that I will use `IN` operator (for the simplicity), instead of using a **long version** (example for the first bar):

`CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "0-5") + CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "05-10")`

However, IN operator doesn't seem to work as I thought it would:

`CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "0-5")` -> returns 10,000

`CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "05-10")` -> returns 20,000

**Long version**:
`CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "0-5") + CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "05-10")` -> returns 30,000 (this is what I want)

**Short version** (with IN):
`CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] IN {"0-5", "05-10"})` -> returns 20,000 (incorrect; IN seems to always return the value for the second reference)

Could you please help me adjusting my formula so that it returns the correct result (30,000)? I'm happy to provide some further information if needed.

**Edit**:
here's an exemplary dataset - left table (Table1) and right table (Table2):
[image]

In PowerBI, these two tables do not have any relationship in a Data Model. Table2 has two measures:
`m1 = MAX(Table2[F])`
`m2 = MAX(Table2[R])`

Table1 also has two measures (for comparison purposes):

```
mSwitch = 
    SWITCH(
        VALUE(SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[RowNo])),
        1, CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] IN {"0-5", "05-10"}),
        2, CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] IN {"10-15", "15-20"}),
        3, CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] IN {"20-25", "25-30"})
    )

mSwitch2 = 
    SWITCH(
        VALUE(SELECTEDVALUE(Table1[RowNo])),
        1, CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "0-5") + CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "05-10"),
        2, CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "10-15") + CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "15-20"),
        3, CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "20-25") + CALCULATE([m1] + [m2], Table2[Key] = "25-30")
    )
```

As you can see on the screenshot below, there is a difference between mSwitch and mSwitch2 (mSwitch2 returning the correct results):

[image]

Comment: That's odd. It does seem like it should work. Can you provide an example that can replicate this behavior?

Comment: Thank you very much for your time @Alexis, I just updated my post with a small example.

Comment: What does Table2 look like and how are `m1` and `m2` defined?

Comment: Oh is it not visible on my post? Maybe it didn't paste correctly? I pasted a screenshot of both Table1 and Table2 datasets and also the calculations for m1 and m2. Happy to paste it separately if that helps.

Comment: Ah, I see it now. Had to refresh the page.

Comment: :-) no worries. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue isn't to do with `SWITCH` or `IN` but rather how `MAX` works.

The measures `m1` and `m2` find the maximum values in columns `F` and `R`, respectively, under the given filter context. If you limit the filter context to `Key = "0-5"` then the maximum is `5,000` for each but if you set `Key in {"0-5","5-10"}`, then the maximum is `10,000` for each.

If you intend to get a sum, then use `SUM` instead of `MAX` for your measures.

Comment: Oh wow, I wouldn't think that MAX in an underlying measure would cause the issue. Initially, I thought that each would be evaluated separately (give me max on measure1, give me max of measure2, and then return the sum of the two). It looks like I got caught up in the filter context again (which I'm hoping to master in 5-10 years...). Anyways, as always, many many thanks for superb help!